# We roll a standard fair die over and over. What is the expected number of rolls until the first pair of consecutive sixes appears.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, random-variables

During class we split this task into smaller pieces:

Let $X$ = r.v. denoting the result of the first roll

Let $Y_1$ = r.v. denoting the result of the first roll

Let $Y_2$ = r.v. denoting the result of the second roll

Let $Z_1$ = r.v. denoting the number of rolls after the first roll that are needed to obtain two consecutive sizes.

Let $Z_2$ = r.v. denoting the number of rolls after the first TWO rolls that are needed to obtain two consecutive sizes.

The answer is the following:

$$E[X] = Pr[Y_1 \neq 6] E[X | Y_1 \neq 6] + Pr[Y_1 = 6] E[X | Y_1 = 6]$$

After this step, I got very lost. I believe that I'm having a hard time understand how to apply conditional probability to random variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn’t bother with the random variables, though you can easily convert the following argument into those terms. Let $r$ be the expected number of rolls.

- With probability $\frac56$ the first roll is not a $6$; in that case you’re effectively starting over, so you expect to need another $r$ rolls, for a total of $r+1$ rolls (including the initial non-$6$).
- With probability $\frac16$ the first roll is a $6$. With probability $\frac56$ the second roll is not a $6$, and again you are in effect starting over: you expect to need another $r$ rolls, and you’ve already used $2$, so you expect to need $r+2$ rolls altogether.
- With probability $\left(\frac16\right)^2$ the first two rolls are both $6$, and you need $2$ rolls altogether.

Those are the only possibilities, so

$$r=\frac56(r+1)+\frac16\cdot\frac56(r+2)+\frac1{36}\cdot2\;,$$

and it’s straightforward to solve for $r$.

Comment: @BrainM.Scott, is this the technique of conditioning on the first steps? It seems like it. I believe this is powerful tool because most of the solutions fro the problems we've been doing in class have been based on this idea. I never really found it very intuitive but I know get that this is the only "painless" way of answering questions of this nature.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, it is. And yes, it is very often the easiest approach.

Comment: @BrianM.ScottOne last thing on this question: Why aren't we including the case in which the first and the second one to NOT be equal to six, that is, $\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6}  \cdot (r+2)$

Comment: @Joel: It’s already covered by the case in which the first roll is not a $6$.

Comment: This approach is the best and most intuitive one! I can finally understand what's going on!